# Ionic Single Language

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to make my application support only one language (for the components like calendar etc.) even though the device language is a different language.

In this picture, as you can see the application language is Turkish but the buttons and the months are English. I want them all to be Turkish.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like you can see in [the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#month-names-and-day-of-the-week-names):

> At this time, there is no one-size-fits-all standard to automatically
>   choose the correct language/spelling for a month name, or day of the
>   week name, depending on the language or locale

And

> All things considered, the by far easiest solution is to just provide
>   an array of names if the app needs to use names other than the default
>   English version of month and day names. The month names and day names
>   can be either configured at the app level, or individual ion-datetime
>   level.

**App Config Level**

```
//app.module.ts
@NgModule({
...,
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  monthNames: ['janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'mar\u00e7o', ... ],
  monthShortNames: ['jan', 'fev', 'mar', ... ],
  dayNames: ['domingo', 'segunda-feira', 'ter\u00e7a-feira', ... ],
  dayShortNames: ['dom', 'seg', 'ter', ... ],
})
],
...
})
```

**Component Input Level**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Período</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DDDD MMM D, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"
    monthNames="janeiro, fevereiro, mar\u00e7o, ..."
    monthShortNames="jan, fev, mar, ..."
    dayNames="domingo, segunda-feira, ter\u00e7a-feira, ..."
    dayShortNames="dom, seg, ter, ..."></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

And in order to change the text of the buttons:

```
<ion-datetime cancelText="'CustomCancel'" doneText="'CustomDone'" ...></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: It's working, I will mark this as the accepted answer. Can I change the 'Cancel' and 'Done' buttons' languages as well?

Comment: Glad to hear that :) I've just edited the answer to include that as well